# Why are my variables not incrementing?

Tags: c, loops, stack, poker

I'm writing a small poker application in C and I have counters for the number of flushes, straights, etc.

Main function:

```
int main(void) {

    int i, j;
    int numHands = 0;
    int flushCount = 0;
    int straightCount = 0;
    int xOfAKindCount = 0;
    int straightFlushCount = 0;
    int fullHouseCount = 0;
    int isTwoPairCount = 0;

    card deck[DECKSZ] = {0};
    card hand[HAND_SIZE] = {0};

    stack deckStack = {0};
    stack handStack = {0};

    initDeck(deck);
    shuffleDeck(deck);
    reset(&deckStack);

    for (i = 0; i < DECKSZ; i++) {
        push(deck[i], &deckStack);
    }

    do {
        reset(&handStack);
        for (i = 0; i < HAND_SIZE; i++) {
            push(pop(&deckStack), &handStack);
            if (isEmpty(&deckStack)) {
                reset(&handStack);
                shuffleDeck(deck);
                reset(&deckStack);
                for (j = 0; j < DECKSZ; j++) {
                    push(deck[j], &deckStack);
                }
            }
            hand[i] = handStack.s[i];
        }

        numHands += 1;
        arrangeHand(hand);

        flushCount += isFlush(hand);
        straightCount += isStraight(hand);
        xOfAKindCount += isXOfAKind(hand, 2, 0);
        straightFlushCount += isStraightFlush(hand);
        fullHouseCount += isFullHouse(hand);
        isTwoPairCount += isTwoPair(hand);

        printf("Flushes:%d Straights:%d SF's:%d Number of Hands:%d\r",
            flushCount, straightCount, straightFlushCount, numHands);
    } while (1);

    printf("\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My function for the number of flushes:

```
int isFlush(card hand[]) {
    int i, count = 0, result = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < HAND_SIZE-1; i++) {
        if (hand[i].suits != hand[i+1].suits) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == HAND_SIZE)
        result = 1;
    return result;
}
```

When I run the program, the code in the do...while loop is supposed to infinitely loop. For every hand popped off the stack, I want to calculate if it is a flush, straight, etc using functions like my isFlush() function here. The issue is these counters, such as numFlushes, remain at a value of zero. Does anybody know why the counters remain at zero, and how to fix that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop in your `isFlush` function can at most increment the count `HAND_SIZE-1` times. Since `count` starts at `0`, it is never more than `HAND_SIZE-1`.

One option is to start your `count` at `1`, since the first card always counts as 1 towards your flush no matter what suit it is. Anther option is to compare `count` to `HAND_SIZE-1` in your `if` statement. Then you can actually return a non-zero value from `isFlush`.

BTW, if you step through the code with a debugger, you should easily see that your if condition is never met.

Comment: Silly mistake on my part! Thank you, that fixed the issue!